# sys_open is not exported but it is in /proc/kallsyms

Tags: linux, system-calls

I am currently studying about kernel programming. Currently using Linux Kernel Version 3.13.0 on Ubuntu 14.04.1

I have confusion where `sys_open` appears when I run the command `cat /proc/kallsyms | grep sys_open`

But when I read the Kernel code in bootlin `https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.13/source/fs/open.c#`

The `sys_open` symbol is not being exported, to make matters worse...

The file `/lib/modules/<kernel-version>/build/Module.symvers` does not include  the `sys_open` symbol..

Now I am super confused, like is `sys_open` loaded? Can it be used and why is  it even there?..

Many thanks in advance!